# AES Encryption in Postman

Tags: postman

I am doing API testing in postman in an encrypted web application.So I need to encrypt the Payload and decrypt the reponse for each and every request.I had a code using Crypto nodeJS module which works fine in VS code IDE.But I am getting error in Postman.

My Code :

```
'use strict';
const crypto = require('crypto');
const ENC_KEY = ''; // encryption key
const IV = ''; //  initialisation vector
// ENC_KEY and IV can be generated as crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex');

const phrase = "hello";

var encrypt = ((val) => {
    let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('AES-256-CBC', ENC_KEY, IV)
  let encrypted = cipher.update(val, 'utf8', 'base64');
  encrypted += cipher.final('base64');
  return encrypted;
});

var decrypt = ((encrypted) => {
  let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('AES-256-CBC', ENC_KEY, IV);
  let decrypted = decipher.update(encrypted, 'base64', 'utf8');
  return (decrypted + decipher.final('utf8'));
});
```

Following is the error I got in postman :

There was an error in evaluating the Pre-request Script:Error: Cannot find module 'crypto'